# Why XMLHttpRequest return null?

Tags: javascript, xml, xml-parsing, xmlhttprequest

This is a bit strange. I ran this script in different computer and got different result. **In one computer, this code worked but didn't work in another.** Here's my js code:

```
xmlDoc = loadXmlDoc();
printSubClassOf();

function loadXmlDoc(){
    var xmlDom = null;
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhttp.open("GET", "resto.owl", false);
    xhttp.send(null);
    xmlDom = xhttp.responseXML;
    return xmlDom;
}

function printSubClassOf(){
    a = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("SubClassOf");  

    for(i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
        b = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("SubClassOf")[i].childNodes;

        for(j = 0; j < b.length; j++){          
            c = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("SubClassOf")[i].childNodes[j];

            document.write(i + " " + j + " " + c.nodeName + "<br>");
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the XML I tried to parse.

```
<Ontology>
    <SubClassOf>
        <Class IRI="#Chef"/>
        <Class IRI="#Employee"/>
    </SubClassOf>
    <SubClassOf>
        <Class IRI="#Customer"/>
        <Class IRI="#People"/>
    </SubClassOf>
</Ontology>
```

I used Chrome Developer Tools to see what was going on. There was a XHR request with 200 status code but still got this error.

```
a = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("SubClassOf");
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getElementsByTagName' of null
```

I think `printSubClassOf()` finished before `loadXmlDoc()` returns the XML. What do you think? And how to solve this problem? FYI: I ran this on localhost.

Comment: I tried the code you posted, and it worked. Are you trying that exact same code, or something different?

Answer (score 2):

Your xml is invalid. There needs to be a single root node to be valid xml. responseXML will only be populated if the response is valid xml.

Comment: @shankshera is the content type of the file set to text/xml

Comment: I believe you're right, it must be the content type. I tried the OP code using a .xml file, apache served it with the xml content type, and it worked. Renamed the file to .owl, and got the exact same error  as the OP.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me... My responseText and response variables were populating after request but ResponseXML was null. After editing the XML, my requestXML variable populated as I expected.